# tshark: save packets in ring buffer files and apply display filters

Tags: networking, tshark

I need to run tshark to record packets for a long time. While saving the packets I wand to also apply display filters as they are parsed to detect errors.

Not to fill the disk and create huge files I want to use it with `--ring-buffer` option  The problem is that tshark doesn't support to apply display-filters and to save to file in the same time.

I could use `tee` to pipe with tshark or tcpdump, but this doesn't work with the ring buffer files. Or to use 2 separate processes for this, but it is still the problem with the output files being created and deleted.

Is is possible to have this only with tshark? or should I just search for other tool like `tee` that generates the circular buffers?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a combination of [`tcpdump`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) and [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) would be useful to you, as in this example?

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -W 10 -C 1 -w file.pcap -z tshark.sh
```

**Contents of `tshark.sh` executable script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Post processing $1"
tshark -Y "some display filter" -r $1
echo ""
```

After each file has reached its size limit, the `-z postrotate` command will be called, and `tshark` will be able to post-process the file.  This isn't real-time per se, as there will be a delay before `tshark` runs, and it will do so on all packets in the file at once, so you'll get batches of output at a time.  You can control the delay to some degree by experimenting with values passed to `-C`.  Larger values will create bigger files but will also incur larger delays in `tshark` post-processing.

Ideally you could also specify `tcpdump`'s `-G rotate_seconds` option, but the man page currently indicates that, *"If used in conjunction with both **-C** and **-G**, the **-W** option will currently be ignored, and will only affect the file name."* I'm not sure why that's the case, but you might consider filing a [`tcpdump` enhancement bug request](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues) to see if someone is willing to change this behavior.

You should also be aware of [Issue #1015: postrotate-command not run when tcpdump terminated](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/1015).

Comment: Very nice info, thanks. I'll try this and see how it works. Because for me it is no problem if the packets inspection has some delay of a few seconds.